# add text field inside datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

i want add text field to datagrid but doesnot work how can i make it work it view text field in datagrid

```
public void Textboxfielld()
{
    DataGridViewTextBoxColumn textBoxColumn = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
    textBoxColumn.HeaderText = "Quantity";
    textBoxColumn.Width = 50;
    textBoxColumn.Visible = true;
    salesStockBunifuDataGridView.Columns.Add(textBoxColumn);
}
```

i call it it show only  headertext

i want add textfield inside datagrid

Comment: I use a button to trigger your code, and the fields can be added normally. Your code is correct. Please consider other reasons why your code does not work, which requires more information. Have you set the data source for the table?I use a button to trigger your code, and the fields can be added normally. Your code is correct. Please consider other reasons why your code does not work, which requires more information. Have you set the data source for the table? Or did you get some errors when triggering this code?